# adding parameter values inside of parenthesis while using scala.html

Tags: javascript, html, scala

i would like to add dynamic parameter values (not sure if i can call it like this)
to the url in my scala html.

Using javascript, I get userId first and then would like to pass it to @routes.adminController.auth(userId).

Here is my source code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkboxChecked() {
  var checkbox = $('td > input:checked').length;

  if(checkbox == 1){
    var $checked = $('td > input:checked');
    var userId = $checked.parent().next().text();

    ** I would like to add below and make it work**
   //location.href = @routes.AdmnTask.user_set(userId)

  } else {
    alert("Please select 1 User ID to proceed.")
  }

};
</script>
```

After a few attempts, I noticed that I am not able to set some random variable and put into location.href as below.

```
var link = "@routes.AdmnTask.user_set(userId)"
location.href = link
```

Could anyone give me a help with this issue please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't. The Scala is executed server-side, while the Javascript is executed client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you can't use a Javascript variable inside a Scala function, since the Scala is executed server-side and the Javascript client-side.

There's a workaround, though.

If your `@routes.AdmnTask.user_set( ... )` gives you an `URL` with the parameter at the end, like `http://example.com/userSet/1` or `http://example.com/userSet?id=1`, you could create a function that transforms this `URL` into a more generic one :

```
/**
 * Gets the base URL for a given route
 *
 * @param  url Call - The route called with the parameter 0
 * @return The URL base String.
 */
public static String baseUrl(play.api.mvc.Call url){
    return url.toString().substring(0, url.toString().length() - 1);
}
```

This function will cut off the last character from your `URL` String, so that you can use it in your Scala template.

Then, all you need to do in your Scala / Javascript is :

```
location.href = '@yourClass.baseUrl(routes.AdmnTask.user_set(0))' + userId
```

*EDIT: Here is the Scala version of the function above :*

```
def baseUrl(url: play.api.mvc.Call): String = {
  url.toString.substring(0, url.toString.length - 1)
}
```

Comment: can you help me with translating this java code into scala?

Comment: @LennyLani I added it at the end of my answer.

Comment: where should i add this @yourclass? (not so sure what this implies.. ) should i locate this scala class separately or can i just add this method under AdmnTask (controller) ?

Comment: @LennyLani You can place it wherever you want, I personally have a custom class I'm using for all my utility functions. If you name your class Utilities, just use `@Utilities.baseUrl( ... )`

Comment: how about a package? do i need separate  package for this class?
I used conf/routes to redirect pages in other cases, is this same here? 
if so my routes return No QueryString binder found for type play.api.mvc.Call.

  here is my routes: 
`/admin/user/baseUrl         controllers.AdmnTask.baseUrl(url: play.api.mvc.Call)`

Comment: @LennyLani packages are totally up to you, you can build your project any way you want. If you use a package, just precise it in your call : `@yourPackage.Utilities.baseUrl( ... )`. And DON'T ADD A ROUTE for the `baseUrl` function !! `baseUrl` is not a route, it's a function.

Comment: I created urlTask class and located your baseurl function. 
and added 
`location.href = '@controllers.urlTask.baseUrl(routes.AdmnTask.user_set(0))' + userId`
in my html. 
and its now causing compilation error with type mismatch;
 found   : Int(0)
 required: String" 
BTW, ty, very appreciated with your help @Zenoo

Comment: @LennyLani You should read about `Scala Packages`, if you set it up correctly, everything should work. I can't help you with more specific Scala errors.

Comment: somehow it's working now after changing user_set(0) to user_set("0")
Thank you @Zenoo